How to backup edl userdata partition using firehose file on xiaomi snapdragon 652?
Xiaomi mi max helium with locked bootloader snapdragon 652 from the year 2016. Will it be possible to backup and restore the userdata partition after reinstalling the system? To backup and restore, do you use Qualcomm QFIL and QSTP? Is a special USB cable (deep flash cable) required? Is the firehose.mbn file in the helium.tgz file for installing the ROM via fastboot the only file needed for this? Only with edl-mode using adb reboot edl can I make a backup and restore or is the batteryless and test point method necessary?
